# Solaris vs Linux

Tags: linux, solaris

I have a requirement where all the scripts on solaris needs to be copy pasted on linux. I need to do this keeping in mind that the scripts should be linux compatible. I have no idea how I can check the compatibility of these already existing scripts. Note that I do not have the linux environment ready and we are doing a data collection of all such types, please help.

Thanks
Abhinav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have no guarantee, there are too much potential differences:
 * scripts calling Solaris-specific tools.
  check (grep) your scripts for calls to `/bin/*` and `/usr/bin`
 * scripts calling utilities with different options on Linux
  Most times Linux utilities (grep, sed, awk, date) will have more options. Try to install and use the GNU utilities or have some hope that the basic options on Solaris are supported on Linux as well.
 * ksh or bash
When you can, try to install and use bash on Solaris. 
Pay attention to while-loops (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061255/3220113).
Update:
My own experience:
I have migrated a lot of scripts from Solaris to AIX, both ksh. Problems I had were mainly:
 * `if [ -z $var ]` fails on AIX when $var is empty (use `if [ -z
   "$var"]`).
* Not having the `sed -i` option I edited files on place
   using `vi file <<@`
This did not work when called from a remote script, it was missing a correct  $TERM
* crontab scripts did not look at /etc/environment (AIX specific)
* The DST in the home-brewn timezone for date on AIX wasn't working well.
* Different directories (database distribition!)
* Other Java classes and classpaths to be set before launching a java script
* Connection to a mailserver worked different.
Recently I am only working with `bash`. What a relief! `find` that supports `mtime` in minutes, `date` that can jump days, `grep` has beautiful options and even `awk` has found his way to my toolbox. For bash just remember that you never pipe into a while-loop.
Of course you would like an estimate of the work you will have. When you need to port scripts written by yourself during the last 3 years (so you understand what they do and the amount is about 2 years work - you must have been doing other things as well), my personal guess is about 4 months programming and testing.

Comment: Thanks Walter for you response. I went through the scripts on solaris and they rarely have any syntax that might not be compatible with linux. All awk, grep, egrep, cd. pwd etc commands are used. Also, would it be wise to do a 'man' of all these commands on my linux environment to check whether they are compatible or not?

Comment: I updated my answer with some surprises you can get. The `man` pages will not help. You can try reading the `http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ` pages or test some of your current scripts on http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to understand the comments on the scripts.

Comment: Thanks Walter, the shell check is a wonderful tool. That is helping me to decode line by line.